# Change value of a form field based on another input

Tags: javascript

I'll start with the code:

```
<input type="text" name="13939069" alt="2171">
<input type="text" name="2171">
```

Basically the name is the category ID, and when there is an alt value present, it is the id of the parent category.

What needs to happen is when the value of the parent category is changed the value of the child categories are also changed.

Comment: Side note: use [HTML5 `data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data) for custom data storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a fiddle i've made for your simple case: http://jsfiddle.net/shershen08/qhCUr/3/

Comment: Thank you, but it would need to be dynamic, how would that work?

Comment: dynamic what? be more concrete pls

Comment: As in there will be lots of fields with different names and alt attributes, and it would need to be able to work for all of them.

Comment: Thank you!! one last question would the js go about or below the fields?

Comment: didn't get you from first time again ))). key idea is to group all parent fileds by class ".parentFld" and all childs fields by class ".chFiled", and connection btwn them is a data-papa attribute as @James Allardice wrote

Comment: *sorry there was a typo: Basically would I put the javascript above or below the form?

Comment: If that link ever goes bad, your answer will be rendered useless for future readers. Please add the relevant code to the answer itself. Cheers!